# Angular protractor issue when clicking links with id atribute

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, jasmine, protractor

I have an issue with Protractor when clicking on links with html id attribute. It works fine with class attribute. Code snippet is like this,

```
clickNavigationAboutLink(){
return element(by.id('nav_about')).click();
}
```

Html code is like this. I have removed other css classes and style related stuff.

```
<li id="nav_about">
    <a class="top-menu-link" href="/about">
    About
    </a>
</li>
```

I tried several solutions which i found such as,

```
browser.driver.get('angular_app_url');
```

And this as well,

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('angular_app_url');
```

Exact error that i'm getting is,

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Comment: Isn't it this [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1896)?

Comment: No, this is not the issue

Comment: I guess this is not related with protractor. it is related with Jasmine.

Comment: This occurs in Protractor. So it should be related to Proractor. Isn't it?

Comment: Is there anyone to help?

Comment: In general, you will want to click the `<a>` element, not the `<li>`. So it makes sense that the class selector is working better than the id selector, because they point to different elements.